# Affiliation and Conflict Disclosure: Ethnography with Workplace customer’s

Tags: ethics, independent-researcher

I am conducting an ethnographic survey with customers of the company I work for.

I work for an Essential Oil company in the product development corporate department. The company is an MLM, and I obtained customer information during our yearly convention where we announce new products launched, and had one on one conversations and initial consent from the customers to participate.

To protect myself in my paper, how do I disclose that I work for the company, but the study is not sponsored by or representative of the company I work for?

I am trying to get my first ethnographies out there so I can leave this job, and work towards my career in Anthropology.

This study is to understand how people talk about holistic health benefits and beliefs on products, and what the culture of being an independent product sales rep is like without direct and constant support from the company.

I want to know if they feel limited or restricted and more importantly, I want to understand more about where the beliefs of product benefits come from.

So, how do I tell in my informed consent that during the interview/study, I am operating on my own, and not under direction of the company and their info will only be used for this ethnography and nothing I say is representative of the company, and anything discussed will be confidential?

Comment: Are you asking what to write in the resulting paper(s) or something else? A bit unclear.

Comment: Well, to be truthful this is my first independent paper, not following a school rubric, so I guess I’m also not sure. I feel that I need the people I’m interviewing to understand that the the company is not asking me to do this, and if I talk about hypothetical products it doesn’t mean they are being developed

Comment: Where do need to "disclose"?

Comment: And then if I were to publish or post the paper, people will know that I am employed by them but am doing it independently so I don’t get automatically discredited for being an employee, and they didn’t sponsor it. Does that help?

Comment: Did you receive human subjects approval and/or exemption?

Comment: I received verbal approval of 10 participants. I now am getting to write up the informed consent to see if those 10 are still willing to participate

Comment: Did the *company* approve your using their customer list for your own independent research?  If not, then all ethics aside, this is likely to get you fired.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is to put a paragraph (Disclosure: ...) in the paper you write saying what you say here. You are employed at X, the subjects are customers, the company is not involved in any way and has no control.

Your affiliation is probably just "Independent Researcher" with a permanent email address.

However, there are some issues. You probably need to get approval from an ethics committee since you are using human subjects. Universities provide these to faculty and research organizations do also, but in the US it is an IRB (Institutional Review Board). There are laws in various places requiring pre-approval of research with human subjects. The laws are in place to protect safety and privacy of subjects, even when it is only questionnaires.

I believe that there are other organizations that provide such approval for a fee.

You probably need written waivers from your subjects, not just verbal. But a review committee/board will give proper advice on that, as well as data retention, etc.

Note that in the past there have been some terribly unethical studies, resulting in the current laws and regulations.

Comment: Yes, _written_ waivers, in my understanding of current U.S. regs.

Comment: That’s helpful! I think I was over thinking how to go about it. I was on the IRB site about the process as well. I was worried about ensuring that the participants understood my employment was not related to this